# Sequelize, bulk create in more then one table, fail all creates if there is an error

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

- agent
- organisation
- agentorganisation

I want to create A new agent (id: 1) and link it to an organisation (id:3)
But for some reason my code adds a record in agentorganisation as:

agentId: 1, (this is a DataTypes.INTEGER)

organisationId: 'bla' (this is a DataTypes.INTEGER)

This generates an error for agentorganisation and won't inject it, but the agent will be injected in the agent table. This will create bad data and I want to evoid it.

So my question:

How can I cancel all the creates if one fails?

Answer (score 5):

Use transactions http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/transactions/

```
sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
  model.bulkcreate(data, { transaction: t });
});
```